# I tried to do tensorflow , but some errors occured

Tags: python, tensorflow

Anyone, please help me.

My environment is Windows10,Anaconda4.4.0,Python 3.5.4.

I installed Tensorflow and

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

typed this code.
But,

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I saw a lot of sites,and tried  a lot of things to do this.
These are all that I checked.
Fitst, cublas64_80.dll,nvblas64_80.dll,cudnn64_5.dll are ilocated in

> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin

And, this location are set as "PATH".

What should I do? Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Tensorflow version please. Also try: https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c

Comment: @JCooke Thank you for your reply!
Tensorflow version is 1.2.1.
Ah..I'm sorry, but I want ask you more questions.
How can I run the source that you showed me? I don't know where to place the source file.

Comment: Try the link above and see what result you get please

Comment: @JCooke
Ah..you mean this one?
"(tf1) C:\Users\**>python check.py
  File "check.py", line 110
    if not cudnn5_found and not cudnn6_found):
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: Yes there is an error in @mrry script. FInd on line 110:
`if not cudnn5_found and not cudnn6_found):`
and replace with
`if not cudnn5_found and not cudnn6_found:` and run again please

Comment: @JCooke
"Could not find cuDNN 6. and Could not load 'cudart64_80.dll'."
Now I know why the program doesn't run.

But, I ran cuda_8.0.61.2_windows.exe and put "cudnn64_5.dll" to the same folder(.../v8.0/bin). 
And,How can I get "cudart64_80.dll "?

Comment: @JCooke
Thank you so much for your reply!
But the case closed because JamesShiztar taught me to install conda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd bet you have installed Tensor-flow is a different Python virtual environment.

To resolve:

```
* Open a Conda terminal
* Open AnacondaNavigator
* Environment tab
* Green arrow by environment name
* Open terminal

In terminal hit> "conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow"
```

Watch it install, close terminal, reopen your Notebook, and It should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I succeeded!!

Comment: Note that if you install via conda and not with pip your version of Tensorflow is not officially supported. You can still install using pip inside a conda environment and it will ensure you have the latest version direct from Google and not a community version from conda! Good luck!

Comment: Nice, please up vote my answer. Desperate to get my rep up!